# php truncate file path to display file name

Tags: php, function, filenames, truncate

Trying to display filename but code is resulting in full file url displaying

```
 if (trim($s) == "") continue;
     $arrfilename = explode("\/", $s);
     $shortfilename = $arrfilename[count($arrfilename)-1];
     $path_parts = pathinfo($s);
     $dir = $path_parts['dirname'];
     $basename = $path_parts['basename'];
     $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
     $fn = $path_parts['filename'];
     $sliderimage = $dir . '/' . $fn . '.' . $ext; 
     if (!file_exists($sliderimage) && !file_exists('../' . $sliderimage)) $sliderimage = $s;
    
     $output .= '[setslideshowlinkattributes ssrs="' . $s . '"]<img  src="/' . $sliderimage . '" alt="' .$shortfilename . '" /></a>';
    }
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= ' <div id="htmlcaption" style="display: inline;">' . $this->options->slideshowcaption . '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
```

Comment: Please add info about the data that you are working with, expected input and expected output...

Comment: output I am seeing `wp-content/uploads/user/userpost/image.jpg`
output I what to see `image`

Comment: PHP has a build in function that gets the filename from a complete path, I'm sure if you Google that you will find allot of examples

Comment: this code worked when it was `  $arrfilename = split("\/", $s);` so not sure why it stopped working after changing out split for explode

Comment: It will be a lot shorter if you use [basename](https://www.php.net/basename)

Comment: so something like this `$shortfilename = basename($s, '.' .$path_parts['extension']);`

Comment: Luuk using baseline was the answer, thank you, if you put that in as the answer ill accept it so you get the points

`$shortfilename = basename($s,'.'.$path_parts['extension']);`